# Build a simple Expression Tree in .NET

Tags: .net, linq-expressions

I have a interface in that user indicates some elements and operators between them and I should display the result.

User can build then a filter like `p1 OP v1 OR p2 OP v2` where `p1` and `p2` are `Person` properties, like `Age, Name, Location` etc, `v1` and `v2` are comparative values(10, 'Maria', 'L.A.'), OP are comparison operators (=, <, >) and OR is a logical operator(can be also AND).

Eg:
`Age > 18 AND Location = 'Paris'`, or another one like
`Name Contains 'andro' AND Sex = 'm'`

Having `myPeople` collection and this filter string, how can I Build and apply this expression using Linq.Expressions?

I tried to use [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), but actually I have a problem using "Where" on `List<Person>`, apparently is not `IQueryable`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use it with `List<T>`, I wouldn't bother using expression trees to start with:

```
public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate1,
                                  Func<T, bool> predicate2)
{
    return t => predicate1(t) || predicate2(t);
}

public static Func<T, bool> And<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate1,
                                   Func<T, bool> predicate2)
{
    return t => predicate1(t) && predicate2(t);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Func<Person, bool> isAdult = person => person.Age > 18;
Func<Person, bool> isInParis = person => person.Location == "Paris";

var personInParis = And(isAdult, isInParis);
```

For the equivalent for expression trees if you want those later, look at [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

The tricky bit is likely to be converting your string into an expression tree to start with.

If Dynamic LINQ does everything *else* you want, you can just use [`AsQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) to create an `IQueryable<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: the problem is in the real project number of predicates is unknown - the user can add filters how many it wants. So, what should I do finally with this `var adultPersonInParis`, apply it in a Where clause?

Comment: @serhio: Just keep building a predicate - start off with something which *always* returns true, and apply AND and OR appropriately. Look at the PredicateBuilder link for more details - the above is the same idea, just applied to delegates instead of expression trees.